# How to pass json in testing APIs using pytest

Tags: pytest, falconframework

In falcon 1.1.0, the only way to send data is through body which takes byte data. How can we post json in such a situation using the simulate_post method while testing falcon APIs using pytest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *body* to send JSON as a string:

```
data = json.dumps(data)
client.simulate_request(method='POST', path=url, body=data)
```

Optionally you can also set the *content-type* header to indicate it's a JSON request:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps(data)
client.simulate_request(method='POST', path=url, headers=headers, body=data)
```

Comment: Second option worked fine. With the first one it was not able to decode as json somehow

Comment: @AyushiDalmia Great. Yes, I think some http clients default to JSON but specifying the mime type is good practice anyway. If this worked for you please accept the answer.